# How are commands and their functions defined in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

Does Java use libraries to determine which commands perform specific actions?

After learning Java for a few weeks now I don't really understand how Java recognises which commands perform specific functions in code.

For example, how does Java know what to do when you use a "do while" loop? And how does Java remember so many different commands, is there some sort of master list or a combination of libraries that document recognised Java commands and their functions?

This may seem like a real noob question, but it's been bugging me for a while and is getting in the way of my understanding of how code, and specifically Java works. Thank you all in advance.

Edit: Just to make this more specific, I was confused because I didn't know how new functionality is added. So, as I understand, new commands and functionality is added to Java using additional packages alongside the JDK, which contains a list of the most fundamental Java commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands and the full syntax of the language is defined in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). The Java compiler generates low level instructions (i.e. bytecode) according to that syntax for language constructs like the `do-while` loop. The JVM is then responsible for executing those bytecodes.

Answer (score 3):

I understood your questions in two ways:
1 - Where does java hold its lots of functions, classes, etc.

2 - How does java work (how does an if/else work) under the code's skin.

First, there is no noob questions, we are all here to learn :)

Second, about the questions:
1 - Java holds its classes in the Java Development Kit (JDK). Because of this, when you create a Java application, you need it installed in your machine, so Java will find a lot of its classes in the installed JDK.

You can expand the amount of classes by adding new packages (jars) to your project. Then, Java will see all the JDK classes and your added jars.

2 - If you mean to "how does java work in a do-while loop or something related, you want to learn about javac, java's compiler.
Javac will get your code and transform into an jar file. The Java Virtual Machine interprets the compiled code to do memory operations.

For exanple, when you assign a variable to java, internally you create a space in memory with the datatype's size.
When you do a while loop, the JVM will use other VM functions to do the job.

That's actually a quite advanced question. I think you can find more about what you want  [here](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JavaCodeToByteCode_PartOne.html#loops).

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: thanks Guilio, so essentially instructions for parsing commands in Java is all stored in the JDK? And when people add new functionality and new commands, this is stored in packages?

Comment: Almost! The one who parses the commands in Java is the Java compiler (javac) this guy will transform the lines of code in system commands! The JDK is a package, with Basic Java funcionalities, as javac, the JVM, Basic classes, and other stuff. (You can see a list of componentes here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit). And about new commands: yes, they are stored in "jar" packages. (That essentially is a compressed file that contains your java classes) :). Is it clear now?  If you have any doubt, just ask! :D